# Check constraint referring to other table

Tags: mariadb

I have three table

```
Processor with columns Name and Socket.
Motherboard with columns Name and Socket.
Build with columns Processor[references Processor(Name)] and Motherboard[references Motherboard(Name)]
```

I need to ensure that the Processor and Motherboard being entered into Build have the same Socket.
Since Check Constraints can't refer other values I am looking for alternatives.
I know you can use UDF or Triggers for this but I am beginner and would like some example code to help me out.

Thanks.

Comment: Please read my question again.
I am asking for help to implement the constraint using triggers.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: I am using phpMyAdmin 4.9.1 and MySQL version 10.4.8

Comment: That's a MariaDB version, not a MySQL version. You aren't using MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No trigger needed. You can do this with foreign key constraints.

1. Add a UNIQUE KEY on Processor for the two columns, Name and Socket.
2. Add a UNIQUE KEY on Motherboard for the two columns, Name, and Socket.
3. Make your FOREIGN KEYs in Build reference the two columns. Give just one column to Build called Socket. Use it in both foreign keys. Therefore it must be the same.

---

Here's what it looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE `Processor` (
  `name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `socket` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`name`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`,`socket`)
);

CREATE TABLE `Motherboard` (
  `name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `socket` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`name`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`,`socket`)
);

CREATE TABLE `Build` (
  `Processor` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Motherboard` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Socket` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT `build_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`Processor`, `Socket`)
    REFERENCES `processor` (`name`, `socket`),
  CONSTRAINT `build_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`Motherboard`, `Socket`)
    REFERENCES `Motherboard` (`name`, `socket`)
);
```

This enforces the business rule you wanted. The foreign keys require that `Build.Socket` reference a socket in both `Processor` and `Motherboard`. 
There can only be one value of `Build.Socket` on a given row in `Build`. 
Therefore the socket must be the same in both tables.

Comment: This will not work. Socket is not a primary key. I have multiple processor and motherboards with the same Socket.

Comment: You can make a foreign key reference any unique key. You can make a unique key over the two columns `Name` and `Socket`. That will allow multiple processors to have the same socket, but only if they have different names. That's how multi-column unique keys work: they're a duplicate only if _both_ columns have the same value as another row.

Comment: @BillKarwin Ah, you meant composite keys

Comment: How does this enforce my constraint on Build though?
The Processor and Motherboard added in build must share the same socket.

Comment: in processor table, the name is unique (it's a key) plus, the combination name+socket is unique too. The same for table motherboard. In the build table, you give the socket too. Doing that, processor name + socket are enforced and motherboard + socket too

Comment: I can't have Socket in Build, unfortunately.

I am looking for something like this. (I know this is wrong just to give you guys an idea)

`CREATE TRIGGER checksocket
AFTER INSERT ON build
DELETE FROM build,processor_products pp,motherboard m WHERE pp.socket <> m.socket AND Processor=pp.Name AND Motherboard=m.Name
end;`

Comment: You can't do any SQL statements in a trigger that modify the table that spawned the trigger. I don't know why you can't have socket in the build table. I'm done answering this question.

Comment: I have to use the schema provided to me. That is why I can't have Socket in Build.